# Normal Approximation Question - Data Management

Tags: probability

Q: A student is writing a multiple choice test consisting of 40 questions, each of which provides four possible choices. He is certain that he has 16 questions correct. If he guesses for all of the remaining 24 questions, what is the probability that he will pass the test?

The solution the teacher posted to this questions is in the pic below, but I'm a little confused about it.

I know that the student has to get at least 4 more questions correct to pass the test. I just don't understand why the x value has to be 3.5 AND 4.5? I thought if you used those 2 values, it'd give you the chances of him getting exactly 4 correct and not at least 4 correct. I thought since he has to get a minimum of 4 correct to pass, I thought x would only be 3.5?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the teacher used the distribution to approximate the chance of getting *exactly* $4$ questions right out of the remaining $24$.

Which as you point out is weird (if not plain incorrect!), since to pass the test you need to get $20$ *or more* questions correct ...

But anyway: since the distribution is approximated by a *continuous* function, the teacher needed some way to translate that into the probability for the *discrete* value of $4$, and so approximated that by taking the chance of the continuous value being between $3.5$ and $4.5$

Of course, if you want to know the *exact* probability of getting exactly $4$ more questions right, the teacher could simply have computed:

$$P(4) = {24 \choose 4} \cdot \big( \frac{1}{4} \big)^4 \cdot \big( \frac{3}{4} \big)^{20}$$

... which is about $0.1316$  (so the teacher's approximation  wasn't far off with the $12$%)

But again, to pass the etst presumably the student need $4$ *or more* questions correct out of the remaining $24$, the probability of which is:

$$P(\ge 4) = 1-P(0)-P(1)-P(2)-P(3)=$$

$$ 1 - \big( \frac{3}{4} \big)^{24} - {24 \choose 1} \cdot \big( \frac{1}{4} \big)^1 \cdot \big( \frac{3}{4} \big)^{23} - {24 \choose 2} \cdot \big( \frac{1}{4} \big)^2 \cdot \big( \frac{3}{4} \big)^{22}- {24 \choose 3} \cdot \big( \frac{1}{4} \big)^3 \cdot \big( \frac{3}{4} \big)^{21} \approx$$

$$1-0.0001-0.0008-0.0308-0.0752=0.8931$$